# Fill array with objects using loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to create array filled with objects. Lets say `{ foo: 0}`. Then I want to add property `bar` to each object with different value. For example: value = index of item in array.

It looks like this

```
const table = new Array(10).fill({foo: 0});

for (let i = 0; i < table.length; i += 1) {
    table[i].bar = i;
}
```

What I expected to get is:

```
[
    { foo: 0, bar: 0 },
    { foo: 0, bar: 1 },
    { foo: 0, bar: 2 },
    ...
    { foo: 0, bar: 9 }
]
```

And what I got:

```
[
    { foo: 0, bar: 9 },
    { foo: 0, bar: 9 },
    { foo: 0, bar: 9 },
    ...
    { foo: 0, bar: 9 }
]
```

Why it behaves that way? Where I made mistake?

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/3La1dqb5/25/)**

EDIT
To clarify

I don't want to replace objects in array with new object like `table[i] = {foo: 0, bar: i}`. It creates new object that replaces old one.
I just want to add properties to existing object.

Comment: The reason for this is the value you bind to the bar attribute is **i** which at the end off the loop is equal to 9 which will bind to every loop instance.

Comment: @Miaan That's not correct.  It's because the array is populated with the same object so when you change anything in the array, you change them all.  The loop is not needed to see this issue.

Comment: Yes Archer is right.

Comment: I understand what is happenning im just bad at explaining

Comment: @Miaan Paste this into your console and then check the results... `var table = new Array(10).fill({foo: 0}); table[3].bar = 25; console.log(table);`  (notice it only changes 1 property - nothing to do with loops at all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Array.fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) takes a value and populates the array with it.
Since non-primitives (objects, arrays) are passed by reference, modification of any item will cause the rest to change as well.

Instead, you can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and pass the object to its mapping function:

```js
const table = Array.from({length:10}, _ => ({foo:0}));

for (let i = 0; i < table.length; i += 1) {
    table[i].bar = i;
}

console.log(table);
```

Answer (score 4):

Your array, has a reference to one single object. So what is happening, is that you're updating the same underlying object. If you're familiar with C, it would be like having N pointers to the same underlying object. No matter which N pointer you operate on, you will change the base underlying object.

```
const table = new Array(10)

for (let i = 0; i < table.length; i += 1) {
   table[i] = {foo: 0, bar: i}
}
```

This will create a new object for each entry in your array

Comment: Ok, I got it. But I don`t want to populate array at once. I want to add new properties to existing objects in array without modifying other properties.

Comment: @kotlet Create the array as above, just remove the `bar` property.  Then you can add and populate `bar` later, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, you are looking for something like this:

```js
const table = new Array(10);

for (let i = 0; i < table.length; i += 1) {
    table[i] = {'foo': 0, 'bar': i};
}

console.log(table)
```

One liner solution using `ECMAScript-6`:

```js
const table = Array.from(new Array(10).keys()).map(e => ({'foo': 0, 'bar': e}))

console.log(table)
```